# Tell Angular's typescript compiler to ignore html template files

Tags: angular, typescript

We have a use case that requires us to silence all html typescript errors in our project, temporarily while we test a library.

Disabling using any (https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any) does not work for us as it is laborious and requires us to do that in over 200 places in our code.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable [template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) by setting `strictTemplates` to `false` in `tsconfig`.

Comment: The documentation says "In the most basic type-checking mode, ..., Angular validates only top-level expressions in a template."

But what I want is no typescript validation, whatsoever on my templates.